# ng-change not firing after click on each radio button in a list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am creating a small application for my college project, I have a scenario where when the user clicks on a radio button an event should be fired.

My Angular code block:

```
<div ng-repeat="q in questionList " ng-if="ExamOver == false">
      <h2>{{count+1}} .{{q.questionText}}</h2>
      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="d in q.Choices">
              <input type="radio" name="isCorrect" ng-model="correctAnswer.isworking" ng-change="getDetails($index,d,correctAnswer.isCorrect);" value="Yes" />
              {{d.choiceText}}
          </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

In my controller, I have this code:

```
$scope.correctAnswer = {isCorrect : false};

$scope.getDetails = function (index, choiceList, isCorrect) {    
    /* some logic... */
}
```

The events are firing only once per button, I am trying to work around this for past few hours without any progress, can someone please guide me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Because it's the same `value="Yes"`

Comment: kindly change `ng-change` to `ng-click`

Answer (score 13):

[`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) will be fired when the **value of the variable you binded (with `ng-model`) changed**. Here, all your radio buttons have the same `value="Yes"`. That's is why ng-change is not triggered. From [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange):

> Evaluate the given expression when the user changes the input. The
>   expression is evaluated immediately, unlike the JavaScript onchange
>   event which only triggers at the end of a change (usually, when the
>   user leaves the form element or presses the return key).

The good solution depends of your needs, but where are some ideas:

## Solution 1

Set different values for your inputs:

```
<li ng-repeat="d in q.Choices">
     <input type="radio" 
            name="isCorrect" 
            ng-model="correctAnswer.isworking" 
            ng-change="getDetails($index, d, correctAnswer.isCorrect)" 
            ng-value="$index" />
     {{d.choiceText}}
</li>
```

## Solution 2

Fire your function whenever a radio is clicked:

```
ng-click="getDetails($index, d, correctAnswer.isCorrect)"
```

Comment: Solution 2 would be an better +1`

Comment: @Ramesh Yes, I think as well. But we need more info to really what would be the best imo. For example, I'm pretty sure there are too many parameters in the `getDetails` function, and we can remove 1-2 to make it simpler.

Comment: yes.  we can get all things from the `d` parameter which we want to do.

Answer (score 3):

[ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) gets triggered if the value of ngModel changes.

Your radio buttons all have the same value namely "Yes"

```
<input type="radio" name="isCorrect" ng-model="..." ng-change="..." value="Yes" >
```

Comment: my request is please use `ng-value` instead of `value`